# Need to decrypt smime p7m file with private key on smart card from UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, mimekit

I have a requirement to decrypt p7m attachments using a private key which is stored on the smart card.

I'm currently able to obtain the private key in the smart card by enumerating all Certs into a CryptogrphicKey object like so:

```
CryptographicKey key = null;
try {
key = await PersistedKeyProvider.OpenKeyPairFromCertificateAsync(Cert, 
HashAlgorithmNames.Sha256, 
CryptographicPadding.RsaPkcs1V15);
}
```

and currently, I'm reading in the p7m file from local folder like this:

```
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
var filebytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
stream.Read(filebytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
var ms = new MemoryStream(filebytes);
ApplicationPkcs7Mime p7m = new 
ApplicationPkcs7Mime(SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData, ms);
```

Like to know if what I'm doing is achievable using Mimekit...

Thanks!

Edit:

After suggestion from Jeff, I did this:

```
CryptographyContext.Register(typeof(WindowsSecureMimeContext));
```

And then it was just a matter of calling:

```
if (p7m != null && p7m.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData)
p7m = p7m.Decrypt() as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;   
if (p7m != null && p7m.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.CompressedData)
p7m = p7m.Decompress() as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;            
if (p7m != null && p7m.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.SignedData)
{
p7m.Verify(out MimeEntity entity);
MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(entity);
}
```

However, problem is, I need to be able to do this from a UWP application... And I cannot access  WindowsSecureMimeContext from there. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can convert the `CryptographicKey` into a key usable by BouncyCastle, then it should be possible to subclass [TemporarySecureMimeContext](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Cryptography_TemporarySecureMimeContext.htm) (or any of the other classes that derive from [BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Cryptography_BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext.htm)), override the [GetPrivateKey](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_Cryptography_TemporarySecureMimeContext_GetPrivateKey.htm) method and you should be Good-To-Go(tm).

The `IX509Selector` parameter is just a way of finding the right private key to use, but if you already know that, then just return your CryptographicKey converted to a BouncyCastle `AsymmetricKeyParameter` and things will work.

If you can't convert it to an `AsymmetricKeyParameter`, then you might need to subclass [SecureMimeContext](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Cryptography_SecureMimeContext.htm) instead, but unfortunately this will require a lot more work because you'll need to override a lot more methods that provide the crypto logic. But if whatever library you are using to read the smart card has its own crypto API, then it shouldn't be too difficult.

For what it's worth, if you have to subclass `SecureMimeContext` directly in order to use another crypto library, I would recommend taking a peek at the [WindowsSecureMimeContext](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/MimeKit/Cryptography/WindowsSecureMimeContext.cs) source code which is an alternative implementation to the BouncyCastle stuff and *may* help you implement your own S/MIME context much more easily if your smart card library has a decent high-level API. The file looks large (~1200 lines) but it's at least 50% comments, so it's really not bad and you could probably get away w/o implementing half of it (i.e. the logic to sign or encrypt since you only need to decrypt).

**Update**:

I'm not very familiar with UWP's Windows.Security namespace, but here's what I came up with as a possible solution (may need work, this code is completely untested and you'll likely need to customize it a bit to use the correct certificate stores, etc):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates;

using Org.BouncyCastle.Cms;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Smime;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509.Store;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;

using MimeKit.IO;

namespace MimeKit.Cryptography
{
    public class UWPSecureMimeContext : SecureMimeContext
    {
        readonly CertificateStore userStore;

        public UWPSecureMimeContext (CertificateStore userStore)
        {
            this.userStore = userStore;

            // UWP does not support Camellia...
            Disable (EncryptionAlgorithm.Camellia256);
            Disable (EncryptionAlgorithm.Camellia192);
            Disable (EncryptionAlgorithm.Camellia192);

            // ... or Blowfish/Twofish...
            Disable (EncryptionAlgorithm.Blowfish);
            Disable (EncryptionAlgorithm.Twofish);

            // ...or CAST5...
            Disable (EncryptionAlgorithm.Cast5);

            // ...or IDEA...
            Disable (EncryptionAlgorithm.Idea);

            // ...or SEED...
            Disable (EncryptionAlgorithm.Seed);
        }

        public UWPSecureMimeContext (string userStore) : this (CertificateStores.GetStoreByName (userStore))
        {
        }

        public UWPSecureMimeContext () : this (CertificateStores.GetStoreByName ("MimeKit"))
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check whether or not the cryptography context can encrypt to a particular recipient.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Checks whether or not the cryptography context can be used to encrypt to a particular recipient.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if the cryptography context can be used to encrypt to the designated recipient; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
        /// <param name="mailbox">The recipient's mailbox address.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <paramref name="mailbox"/> is <c>null</c>.
        /// </exception>
        public override bool CanEncrypt (MailboxAddress mailbox)
        {
            if (mailbox == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (mailbox));

            return GetRecipientCertificate (mailbox) != null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check whether or not a particular mailbox address can be used for signing.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Checks whether or not as particular mailbocx address can be used for signing.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if the mailbox address can be used for signing; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
        /// <param name="signer">The signer.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <paramref name="signer"/> is <c>null</c>.
        /// </exception>
        public override bool CanSign (MailboxAddress signer)
        {
            if (signer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (signer));

            return GetSignerCertificate (signer) != null;
        }

        static byte ToXDigit (char c)
        {
            if (c >= 0x41) {
                if (c >= 0x61)
                    return (byte) (c - (0x61 - 0x0a));

                return (byte) (c - (0x41 - 0x0A));
            }

            return (byte) (c - 0x30);
        }

        static byte[] HexDecode (string value)
        {
            var decoded = new byte[value.Length / 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < decoded.Length; i++) {
                var b1 = ToXDigit (value[i * 2]);
                var b2 = ToXDigit (value[i * 2 + 1]);

                decoded[i] = (byte) ((b1 << 4) | b2);
            }

            return decoded;
        }

        async Task<Certificate> GetCertificate (MailboxAddress mailbox, bool sign)
        {
            var secure = mailbox as SecureMailboxAddress;
            var query = new CertificateQuery ();
            var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

            if (secure != null)
                query.Thumbprint = HexDecode (secure.Fingerprint);
            else
                query.FriendlyName = mailbox.Address;

            // TODO: filter on key usages

            foreach (var certificate in await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync (query)) {
                if (certificate.ValidFrom > now || certificate.ValidTo < now)
                    continue;

                return certificate;
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the certificate for the specified recipient.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// <para>Gets the certificate for the specified recipient.</para>
        /// <para>If the mailbox is a <see cref="SecureMailboxAddress"/>, the
        /// <see cref="SecureMailboxAddress.Fingerprint"/> property will be used instead of
        /// the mailbox address.</para>
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>The certificate to use for the recipient; otherwise, or <c>null</c>.</returns>
        /// <param name="mailbox">The recipient's mailbox address.</param>
        protected virtual Certificate GetRecipientCertificate (MailboxAddress mailbox)
        {
            return GetCertificate (mailbox, false).GetAwaiter ().GetResult ();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the certificate for the specified signer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// <para>Gets the certificate for the specified signer.</para>
        /// <para>If the mailbox is a <see cref="SecureMailboxAddress"/>, the
        /// <see cref="SecureMailboxAddress.Fingerprint"/> property will be used instead of
        /// the mailbox address.</para>
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>The certificate to use for the signer; otherwise, or <c>null</c>.</returns>
        /// <param name="mailbox">The signer's mailbox address.</param>
        protected virtual Certificate GetSignerCertificate (MailboxAddress mailbox)
        {
            return GetCertificate (mailbox, true).GetAwaiter ().GetResult ();
        }

        static byte[] ReadAllBytes (Stream stream)
        {
            if (stream is MemoryBlockStream)
                return ((MemoryBlockStream) stream).ToArray ();

            if (stream is MemoryStream)
                return ((MemoryStream) stream).ToArray ();

            using (var memory = new MemoryBlockStream ()) {
                stream.CopyTo (memory, 4096);
                return memory.ToArray ();
            }
        }

        static async Task<byte[]> ReadAllBytesAsync (Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (stream is MemoryBlockStream)
                return ((MemoryBlockStream) stream).ToArray ();

            if (stream is MemoryStream)
                return ((MemoryStream) stream).ToArray ();

            using (var memory = new MemoryBlockStream ()) {
                await stream.CopyToAsync (memory, 4096, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait (false);
                return memory.ToArray ();
            }
        }

        static AsymmetricKeyParameter LoadPrivateKey (IBuffer buffer)
        {
            AsymmetricKeyParameter key = null;
            byte[] keyData;

            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray (buffer, out keyData);

            using (var memory = new MemoryStream (keyData, false)) {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader (memory)) {
                    var pem = new PemReader (reader);

                    var keyObject = pem.ReadObject ();

                    if (keyObject != null) {
                        key = keyObject as AsymmetricKeyParameter;

                        if (key == null) {
                            var pair = keyObject as AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;

                            if (pair != null)
                                key = pair.Private;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (key == null || !key.IsPrivate)
                return null;

            return key;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the private key for the certificate matching the specified selector.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Gets the private key for the first certificate that matches the specified selector.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>The private key on success; otherwise <c>null</c>.</returns>
        /// <param name="selector">The search criteria for the private key.</param>
        protected virtual async Task<AsymmetricKeyParameter> GetPrivateKeyAsync (IX509Selector selector)
        {
            // first we need to find the certificate...
            var match = selector as X509CertStoreSelector;
            var query = new CertificateQuery ();

            if (match == null)
                return null;

            if (match.Certificate != null)
                query.Thumbprint = HexDecode (match.Certificate.GetFingerprint ());

            if (match.Issuer != null)
                query.IssuerName = match.Issuer.ToString ();

            var certificates = await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync (query);
            var certificate = certificates.FirstOrDefault ();

            if (certificate == null)
                return null;

            // now get the key

            // TODO: what hash algo/padding do we want? does it matter?
            var key = await PersistedKeyProvider.OpenKeyPairFromCertificateAsync (certificate, HashAlgorithmNames.Sha256, CryptographicPadding.RsaPkcs1V15);
            var buffer = key.Export (CryptographicPrivateKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPrivateKey);

            return LoadPrivateKey (buffer);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the private key for the certificate matching the specified selector.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Gets the private key for the first certificate that matches the specified selector.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>The private key on success; otherwise <c>null</c>.</returns>
        /// <param name="selector">The search criteria for the private key.</param>
        protected virtual AsymmetricKeyParameter GetPrivateKey (IX509Selector selector)
        {
            return GetPrivateKeyAsync (selector).GetAwaiter ().GetResult ();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypt the specified encryptedData.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Decrypts the specified encryptedData.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>The decrypted <see cref="MimeKit.MimeEntity"/>.</returns>
        /// <param name="encryptedData">The encrypted data.</param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <paramref name="encryptedData"/> is <c>null</c>.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsException">
        /// An error occurred in the cryptographic message syntax subsystem.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.OperationCanceledException">
        /// The operation was cancelled via the cancellation token.
        /// </exception>
        public override MimeEntity Decrypt (Stream encryptedData, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken))
        {
            if (encryptedData == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (encryptedData));

            var parser = new CmsEnvelopedDataParser (encryptedData);
            var recipients = parser.GetRecipientInfos ();
            var algorithm = parser.EncryptionAlgorithmID;
            AsymmetricKeyParameter key;

            foreach (RecipientInformation recipient in recipients.GetRecipients ()) {
                if ((key = GetPrivateKey (recipient.RecipientID)) == null)
                    continue;

                var content = recipient.GetContent (key);
                var memory = new MemoryStream (content, false);

                return MimeEntity.Load (memory, true, cancellationToken);
            }

            throw new CmsException ("A suitable private key could not be found for decrypting.");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypt the specified encryptedData to an output stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Decrypts the specified encryptedData to an output stream.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="encryptedData">The encrypted data.</param>
        /// <param name="decryptedData">The output stream.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <para><paramref name="encryptedData"/> is <c>null</c>.</para>
        /// <para>-or-</para>
        /// <para><paramref name="decryptedData"/> is <c>null</c>.</para>
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsException">
        /// An error occurred in the cryptographic message syntax subsystem.
        /// </exception>
        public override void DecryptTo (Stream encryptedData, Stream decryptedData)
        {
            if (encryptedData == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (encryptedData));

            if (decryptedData == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (decryptedData));

            var parser = new CmsEnvelopedDataParser (encryptedData);
            var recipients = parser.GetRecipientInfos ();
            var algorithm = parser.EncryptionAlgorithmID;
            AsymmetricKeyParameter key;

            foreach (RecipientInformation recipient in recipients.GetRecipients ()) {
                if ((key = GetPrivateKey (recipient.RecipientID)) == null)
                    continue;

                var content = recipient.GetContentStream (key);

                content.ContentStream.CopyTo (decryptedData, 4096);
                return;
            }

            throw new CmsException ("A suitable private key could not be found for decrypting.");
        }

        static string GetHashAlgorithmName (DigestAlgorithm digestAlgo)
        {
            switch (digestAlgo) {
            case DigestAlgorithm.MD5: return HashAlgorithmNames.Md5;
            case DigestAlgorithm.Sha1: return HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1;
            case DigestAlgorithm.Sha256: return HashAlgorithmNames.Sha256;
            case DigestAlgorithm.Sha384: return HashAlgorithmNames.Sha384;
            case DigestAlgorithm.Sha512: return HashAlgorithmNames.Sha512;
            default: throw new NotSupportedException ($"The {digestAlgo} digest algorithm is not supported on the Universal Windows Platform.");
            }
        }

        static Certificate GetCertificate (X509Certificate x509)
        {
            var buffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray (x509.GetEncoded ());

            return new Certificate (buffer);
        }

        Stream Sign (Certificate certificate, IList<Certificate> chain, DigestAlgorithm digestAlgo, Stream content, bool detach)
        {
            var signerInfo = new CmsSignerInfo ();
            var signers = new CmsSignerInfo[1];
            byte[] signedData;
            IBuffer buffer;

            signerInfo.HashAlgorithmName = GetHashAlgorithmName (digestAlgo);
            signerInfo.Certificate = certificate;
            signers[0] = signerInfo;

            if (detach) {
                using (var input = content.AsInputStream ())
                    buffer = CmsDetachedSignature.GenerateSignatureAsync (input, signers, chain).GetResults ();
            } else {
                buffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray (ReadAllBytes (content));
                buffer = CmsAttachedSignature.GenerateSignatureAsync (buffer, signers, chain).GetResults ();
            }

            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray (buffer, out signedData);

            return new MemoryStream (signedData, false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cryptographically signs and encapsulates the content using the specified signer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Cryptographically signs and encapsulates the content using the specified signer.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>A new <see cref="MimeKit.Cryptography.ApplicationPkcs7Mime"/> instance
        /// containing the detached signature data.</returns>
        /// <param name="signer">The signer.</param>
        /// <param name="content">The content.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <para><paramref name="signer"/> is <c>null</c>.</para>
        /// <para>-or-</para>
        /// <para><paramref name="content"/> is <c>null</c>.</para>
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException">
        /// An error occurred in the cryptographic message syntax subsystem.
        /// </exception>
        public override ApplicationPkcs7Mime EncapsulatedSign (CmsSigner signer, Stream content)
        {
            if (signer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (signer));

            if (content == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (content));

            var certificate = GetCertificate (signer.Certificate);
            IList<Certificate> chain = null;

            // FIXME: does the chain need to include the signer's cert as well?
            if (signer.CertificateChain.Count > 1) {
                chain = new List<Certificate> (signer.CertificateChain.Count - 1);

                for (int i = 1; i < signer.CertificateChain.Count; i++)
                    chain.Add (GetCertificate (signer.CertificateChain[i]));
            }

            return new ApplicationPkcs7Mime (SecureMimeType.SignedData, Sign (certificate, chain, signer.DigestAlgorithm, content, false));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sign and encapsulate the content using the specified signer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Sign and encapsulate the content using the specified signer.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>A new <see cref="MimeKit.Cryptography.ApplicationPkcs7Mime"/> instance
        /// containing the detached signature data.</returns>
        /// <param name="signer">The signer.</param>
        /// <param name="digestAlgo">The digest algorithm to use for signing.</param>
        /// <param name="content">The content.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <para><paramref name="signer"/> is <c>null</c>.</para>
        /// <para>-or-</para>
        /// <para><paramref name="content"/> is <c>null</c>.</para>
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        /// <paramref name="digestAlgo"/> is out of range.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.NotSupportedException">
        /// The specified <see cref="DigestAlgorithm"/> is not supported by this context.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="CertificateNotFoundException">
        /// A signing certificate could not be found for <paramref name="signer"/>.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException">
        /// An error occurred in the cryptographic message syntax subsystem.
        /// </exception>
        public override ApplicationPkcs7Mime EncapsulatedSign (MailboxAddress signer, DigestAlgorithm digestAlgo, Stream content)
        {
            if (signer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (signer));

            if (content == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (content));

            var certificate = GetSignerCertificate (signer);

            return new ApplicationPkcs7Mime (SecureMimeType.SignedData, Sign (certificate, null, digestAlgo, content, false));
        }

        public override ApplicationPkcs7Mime Encrypt (CmsRecipientCollection recipients, Stream content)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        public override MimePart Encrypt (IEnumerable<MailboxAddress> recipients, Stream content)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        public override MimePart Export (IEnumerable<MailboxAddress> mailboxes)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        public override void Import (Stream stream, string password)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        public override void Import (X509Certificate certificate)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        public override void Import (X509Crl crl)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cryptographically signs the content using the specified signer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Cryptographically signs the content using the specified signer.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>A new <see cref="MimeKit.Cryptography.ApplicationPkcs7Signature"/> instance
        /// containing the detached signature data.</returns>
        /// <param name="signer">The signer.</param>
        /// <param name="content">The content.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <para><paramref name="signer"/> is <c>null</c>.</para>
        /// <para>-or-</para>
        /// <para><paramref name="content"/> is <c>null</c>.</para>
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException">
        /// An error occurred in the cryptographic message syntax subsystem.
        /// </exception>
        public override ApplicationPkcs7Signature Sign (CmsSigner signer, Stream content)
        {
            if (signer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (signer));

            if (content == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (content));

            var certificate = GetCertificate (signer.Certificate);
            IList<Certificate> chain = null;

            // FIXME: does the chain need to include the signer's cert as well?
            if (signer.CertificateChain.Count > 1) {
                chain = new List<Certificate> (signer.CertificateChain.Count - 1);

                for (int i = 1; i < signer.CertificateChain.Count; i++)
                    chain.Add (GetCertificate (signer.CertificateChain[i]));
            }

            return new ApplicationPkcs7Signature (Sign (certificate, chain, signer.DigestAlgorithm, content, true));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sign the content using the specified signer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Sign the content using the specified signer.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>A new <see cref="MimeKit.MimePart"/> instance
        /// containing the detached signature data.</returns>
        /// <param name="signer">The signer.</param>
        /// <param name="digestAlgo">The digest algorithm to use for signing.</param>
        /// <param name="content">The content.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <para><paramref name="signer"/> is <c>null</c>.</para>
        /// <para>-or-</para>
        /// <para><paramref name="content"/> is <c>null</c>.</para>
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        /// <paramref name="digestAlgo"/> is out of range.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.NotSupportedException">
        /// The specified <see cref="DigestAlgorithm"/> is not supported by this context.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="CertificateNotFoundException">
        /// A signing certificate could not be found for <paramref name="signer"/>.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException">
        /// An error occurred in the cryptographic message syntax subsystem.
        /// </exception>
        public override MimePart Sign (MailboxAddress signer, DigestAlgorithm digestAlgo, Stream content)
        {
            if (signer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (signer));

            if (content == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException (nameof (content));

            var certificate = GetSignerCertificate (signer);

            return new ApplicationPkcs7Signature (Sign (certificate, null, digestAlgo, content, true));
        }

        public override DigitalSignatureCollection Verify (Stream signedData, out MimeEntity entity, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken))
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        public override Stream Verify (Stream signedData, out DigitalSignatureCollection signatures, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken))
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        public override DigitalSignatureCollection Verify (Stream content, Stream signatureData, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken))
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        public override Task<DigitalSignatureCollection> VerifyAsync (Stream content, Stream signatureData, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken))
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My application is a UWP app, and for some reason the WindowsSecureMimeContext cannot be found in the namespace. When I create a normal C# console app however, it is available... Any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant look at the source code on github. It's not available for UWP because my WindowsSecureMimeContext uses API's from System.Security.dll that are not available on UWP (System.Security was replaced by Windows.Security.dll or something).

Comment: FWIW, now that I know you are on UWP, I might look into adding support for that directly to MimeKit but I don't know when I'll finish it (I am not very familiar with UWP's crypto API's).

Comment: Once I switched to a C# console application, using the WindowsSecureMimeContext you suggested, the decryption was surprisingly straightforward. I didn't even need to bother with obtaining the CryptographicKey any more...
All I did was call: 
    CryptographyContext.Register(typeof(WindowsSecureMimeContext));
and then : 
    p7m = p7m.Decrypt() as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;
    p7m = p7m.Decompress() as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;
    p7m.Verify(out MimeEntity entity);
    MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(entity);
In the order. The API managed to find the corresponding private key on the card.

Comment: I guess, my card reader and smart card were already natively supported by Windows. However, I still need to be able to decrypt the Smime from my UWP app. Since I cannot have access to WindowsSecureMimeContext, do you have any ideas on how I can still achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: I just updated my answer with a rough draft of a UWPSecureMimeContext class.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Sorry, for the late reply. I actually went a slightly different route.. I turned my C# app into a desktop bridge component, which communicates with my UWP app. They are able to pass messages to each other via an app service extension. This way, I'm still able to use the WindowsSecureMimeContext.